# VueJs How to create object with observable properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, vue.js, vue-component

How can I create the equivalent of knockoutjs ViewModel in VueJS? for example:

```
var Person = function() { 
    var self = this;
    this.firstName = ko.observable('');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('');
    this.fullName = ko.computed(
    function() { 
        return self.firstName() + ' ' self.lastName();
    });
```

what is the equivalent of that in VueJs how can I create an object or viewmodel without a template property and without creating it as a component? Do I just create plain javascript objects (function/json object) if so how can I create computed/observable properties in those plain javascript objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Vue, the model is just a pojo. Computed properties are established using its `computed` member. Here's an example from the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) modified for your use case:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#aPerson',
  data: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
})
```

A reusable component that accepts a `person` object would look like this:

```
Vue.component('person', {
  props: ['person'],
  computed: {
    fullName () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what about the case where you don't want the model to be bound to an html element? Like I just want to have an object I can new up but still be able to observe it's properties.

Comment: According to [this post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2859), Vue's observer implementation is intentionally hidden. The author suggests [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) for state management. You may find the [section on observable state](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx#observable-state) useful.
Incidentally, computed properties can be done using standard JavaScript: `var person = { fn: '', ln: '', get fullName() { return this.fn + ' ' + this.ln; } }`